# Any success with "Sign in with Facebook" using FirebaseUI-web on Cordova/iOS web app?

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to use Facebook authentication (i.e. "Sign in with Facebook") in my Cordova web app on iOS, using [firebaseui-web](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), however it doesn't appear to be working for me.

Attempting to sign in with Facebook just redirects back to my (Cordova) app after the login process on facebook.com, with no change to the FirebaseUI auth screen (i.e. no loading indicator), nor anything being logged, even though I am logging to the console in the signInFailure and signInSuccessWithAuthResult callbacks.

I would expect to be either logged in successfully after being redirected back to my Cordova web app, with the signInSuccessWithAuthResult callback called, or to be not logged in successfully, with the signInFailure callback called.

The Facebook authentication works as expected in a regular browser, and Google authentication via firebaseui-web is also working in my Cordova web app on iOS.

Relevant code:

```
const uiConfig = {
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
  privacyPolicyUrl: "https://www.example.com/privacy",
  callbacks: {
    signInFailure: function(error) {
      console.error("signInFailure(): error =", error);
    },
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
      console.log("signInSuccessWithAuthResult(): authResult =", authResult, ", redirectUrl =", redirectUrl);
      return true;
    },
  },
};
```

```
let authUi = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance();
if (!authUi) {
  authUi = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
}

if (authUi.isPendingRedirect()) {
  console.log("isPendingRedirect() is true");
}

authUi.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
```

See https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/565 for more details (I'm cross-posting here for more exposure).

Is this working for anyone else?

Comment: Did you get this working - i can't get google or facebook working in cordova ios/android.. it would be good if you can post your config.xml file if you have it working. thanks.

Comment: @GMan what issues are you encountering? It would help if you described your issue in a new question. After scouring the internet of course :)